# Service Stack (4.5.0) Swagger UI

Tags: swagger, servicestack

I have added the swagger feature plugin to an existing service stack API, which enables swagger UI and renders the end points for the developers to try out.

I need to modify the swagger UI and for that I have downloaded the swagger-ui folder and added to the root of the project. However, it doesn't render the changes that I have made to the UI. I believe it renders the swagger UI from embedded resources.

What configuration do I need to add so that it creates the swagger UI from files in the file system? I did look into the following documentation but its not clear.

http://docs.servicestack.net/virtual-file-system

Please note that currently I am using version 4.5.0 of service stack.

Answer (score 1):

For the latest Swagger 2.0 UI you should use the [OpenApiFeature plugin](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi)  the docs show how you can [override the Embedded Resources by placing modified copies in your projects /swagger-ui/ folder](http://docs.servicestack.net/openapi#overriding-openapi-embedded-resources)

Comment: Thank you. I will review the documentation in more detail.